# gephi-toolkit - create a new Importer to get data from a collection

Tags: java, graph, talend, gephi

I'm building a component for Talend Open Studio for network analysis and I plan to using gephy toolkit, but input data must come from a dataflow (to keep simple let's say a java collection)  while gephy-toolkit let you import only from files (lot of different kinds, actually) or even rdbms, but not from java collections.

how can i build a new simple custom importer (if it can be build at first place. It seems possible, at least for GUI gephi cfr. http://wiki.gephi.org/index.php/HowTo_write_an_import)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution by myself: I need to create a Spigot Importer.

- the factory

  ```
  @ServiceProvider(service = ImporterBuilder.class)
  public final class TalendCollectionImporterBuilder implements ImporterBuilder {

  public String getName() {
         return "Talend Flow Connection Importer";
      }

      public SpigotImporter buildImporter() {
         return new TalendCollectionImporter();
      }

  }
  ```
- the importer (stub)

  ```
  public class TalendCollectionImporter implements SpigotImporter {

          private ContainerLoader container;
          private Report report;
          private ProgressTicket progressTicket;
          private boolean cancel = false;

          public boolean execute(ContainerLoader loader) {
              this.container = loader;
              this.report = new Report();

              // import stuff

              return !cancel;
          }

          public ContainerLoader getContainer() {
              return container;
          }

          public Report getReport() {
              return report;
          }

          public boolean cancel() {
              cancel = true;
              return true;
          }

  }
  ```